# Rocheworlds mass

Tags: planets, space, stars

Suppose you've got two tidally-locked planets, each one orbiting its own red dwarf. With two red dwarfs to hold the planets, could the planets get close enough to share atmospheres? And how would you calculate the potential mass allowable to each planet based on the counter-pull of the red dwarfs

Comment: Downvotes without comments are unhelpful, especially for new users.

Comment: Picture or it didn't happen. I don't understand at all how the system is supposed to look like.

Comment: @AlexP *Rocheworld* by Robert L. Forward.

Comment: Binary red dwarfs. Each has a tidal-locked planet. Binary stars are fairly common. Could their planets ever get close enough to share atmosphere? Are we sure it's impossible?

Comment: It's a valid question and I don't see a reason to downvote. How do you imagine the orbits of the two red dwarves? you can use this simulator and post the settings: http://www.astro.ucla.edu/undergrad/astro3/orbits.html

Answer (score 4):

What you describe is an unstable system.

For a body A to orbit another body B, A has to be within the sphere of gravitation influence of B, called Hill sphere. In your case A is in the Hill sphere of B, and A' is in the Hill sphere of B'.

If A and A' get close enough to share atmosphere, it means that they will also be at the borders of both Hill spheres. In this situation any small perturbation will make one or both be pulled out of their regular orbit, or even worse collide with each other and then be pulled out of the orbit.

A collision is a way of sharing atmosphere, on the other hand.

Comment: Does it have to be unstable, though?  The basic system certainly is for the reason you give, but what about resonance effects?

Comment: @LorenPechtel Unless the red dwarves orbit each other while keeping EXACTLY the same distance you are going to have perturbations which will move the planets relative to each other. A collision or a push out of orbit is extremely likely.

Comment: @LorenPechtel If they were close enough to share atmosphere then this would slow them down both. Their orbits would be altered becoming more elliptical and this would lead to a collision.

Comment: @DuncanDrake What I'm wondering is if a resonance could keep them stable.  They're obviously unstable otherwise.  I'm thinking of the novel where they appear to be in an resonance with Gargantua, could that not keep them stable?

Comment: @LorenPechtel am not familiar with the novel and don't know what Gargantua is. Anyway stability through resonance would imply conditions that are so unlikely (everything must be of the proper size and at the proper distance) that would be unbelievable. Unless it had been setup by the Great Maker himself of course. -.-

Comment: @DuncanDrake Gargantua is a super-Jovian planet that the Rocheworld orbits around in an elliptical orbit--the three worlds line up at every periapsis which basically implies resonance.  And a resonance orbit doesn't require a perfect setup--anything near a resonance will get pulled into resonance.

Comment: Could a heavy third body intervene with a longer revolution time and gravitationally tug the rocky planets out of an increasingly elliptical orbit, pulling them back before they physically smash into each other?